# Techniques to combat sexism at school level

Tags: social-psychology, abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology, reproducible-research, sexual-assault

I am from India, and if you take a glance at the daily news you will see a lot of gruesome gangrapes and murders. [Nirbhaya,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Delhi_gang_rape_and_murder)  [Kathua rape case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathua_rape_case) and the [Hathras gangrape](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/hathras-gangrape-and-murder-case-how-the-case-has-unfolded-so-far/articleshow/78410835.cms)
There are other such incidents all around the globe.
Unfortunately, the masses in India are still [loyal believers in sexism](https://www.businessinsider.com/heres-what-most-indian-men-think-about-rape-2015-3?IR=T) and all the "rules and regulations on women "it entails.

And unfortunately the sex education taught to us at middle school and high school mostly focuses on that these changes as puberty are normal, and why it is wiser to not get pregnant at the age of 15 years. Various contraceptive methods ,venereal diseases .A very short ,glossed over mention of sexual crimes and no explanation why it's wrong.

There are many ways proposed to change the rape culture and in bringing the rapists and victims to justice ,like police reforms, law enforcements , death penalty, fast track courts for child rapists.
Even school workshops, seminars have been conducted, along with workplace training against sexual abuse.
But sex and its related topics are still seen as a [taboo topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_India) and the school centered education isn't very effective.

Coming from a place where non consensual sex is glorified and pop culture depict it too often,I know that [rape is about both power and sex.](https:///www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/insight-therapy/201602/rape-is-not-only-about-power-it-s-also-about-sex) What I think could be a step towards eradicating this is by teaching the [real life stories of rape survivors](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/teen-angst/201311/surviving-rape-part-one) and how they bounced back, just like the biography of any famous person.

I know that there are many [informational videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWotws3ZMethMPb3fC3pBDkM6MlsSCA54) available on the internet, but many parents are still against such content, for fear of "polluting" their innocent children's minds. Moreover, many parts of rural India don't have much access to the internet.

So my main question is that have such approach to introduce sexual assault into literature tried out before? Or any other methods? how have these worked out? What are the underlying basis for such methods?

If any relevant research articles are available, please provide links. Eager to read up any articles.

P.S:*I know that very few users are from India and I didn't find any specific Stack Exchange site for teaching methodology in general, so I am posting this question in this site.*

Comment: Problems linked with rape are not just in India. There are issues with how rape is viewed across the world. Rape of certain people is seen as a cure for AIDS etc. in some cultures. The thing is, the question on how these problems are dealt with involves a system of cultural change. I think that how that is done is dependent on the culture, and all cultures are struggling to come up with a full solution. No culture, class, race or sex is free of rape.

Comment: @Chris Roger yes ,different cultures have different hurdles unique to them, but I hope that since sexual assault spans the entire globe and also has many historical aspects, maybe some research has been done on how to combat the mentality and reasoning behind the act.[link](http://www.history.com/news/sexual-assault-rome-slavery-columbus-jim-crow#:~:text=Nearly%20as%20long%20as%20people%20have%20been%20recording,assaults%20have%20even%20changed%20the%20course%20of%20history.)